# Clicking edge of button is broken in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

On Chrome and Firefox, clicking the edge of a button gives odd behavior:

[image: clicking edge of button, active state triggered but not onclick event]

The CSS active state is triggered, but not the JavaScript onclick event. Only at the VERY EDGE of the button.

I tried changing the button border-width (no border and also a thick border). No difference.

It happens in Chrome, Firefox, & Opera. But not in Safari. I haven't tested Edge or IE.

Here is the exact code used to test this:

```js
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
```

```css
button:active {
  transform: scale(.9);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Seems to be related to the CSS scaling. I can repro the issue with the rule, but not without it

Comment: Probably because when the scaling changes, the mouse is no longer on the button.

Comment: I reduced the scaling to 0.5, then the problem appears when I click anywhere near the edge.

Comment: A click is only registered if the mouse is on the element when you press and release the mouse button. But when you press down, the CSS shrinks the element, so the mouse is no longer on the element when you release it. It's just like pressing the mouse button and moving the mouse away before releasing.

Comment: I think you would see the same effect if you had a `translate` CSS that moved the button far enough that it's no longer under the mouse.

Comment: Oh ok, I see. So a click event requires both the mousedown and mouseup event to happen on the element. So when the mousedown event happens, the button is scaled down, and then the cursor is no longer above the button when the mouseup event happens.

Comment: So for my particular case I should use a mousedown event, instead of click. Is there a downside to using mousedown event over click event?

Answer (score 1):

The CSS state is changed on mouse down. However to register the click, both mouse down and mouse up needs to be on the button. If I do a mouse down on the button, then move the mouse outside and let go, you see that style effect, but no click event is registered.

[image: screencast button click]

Because of the `scale(.9)`, the mouse pointer is no longer over the button on mouse up when pressing near the edge.

Comment: Is there a downside to using mousedown event instead of click event?

Comment: How do you then activate the button with keyboard only? Click event enables this by default.

Comment: Mouse down is the event that happens when you press down on the mouse button before you let go. It's internal. The javascript "mousedown" event is not used. Also, this has nothing to do with the keyboad.

Comment: @cloned Ah I see. So with a click event the button is still keyboard accessible, but with mousedown it is not. Is there a good way to make the mousedown event keyboard accessible? Or should I simply use click event over mousedown as often as possible? In your opinion

Comment: A keyboard doesn't have a mouse button. Same goes for tablets and phones, but I think they might still be triggering iton touch. So only click event is really usable by all without any hassle.